# Parallel.ForEach and IGrouping source item issue

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to parallelize a query with a groupby statement in it. The query is similar to

```
    var colletionByWeek = (
                             from item in objectCollection
                             group item by item.WeekStartDate into weekGroups
                             select weekGroups
                          ).ToList();
```

If I use Parallel.ForEach with shared variable like below, it works fine. But I don't want to use shared variables in parallel query.

```
var pSummary=new List<object>();
Parallel.ForEach(colletionByWeek, week =>
                                {
                                    pSummary.Add(new object()
                                    {
                                        p1 = week.First().someprop,
                                        p2= week.key,
                                        .....
                                    });
                                }
                 );
```

So, I have changed the above parallel statement to use local variables. But the compiler complains about the source type `<IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, object>>` can not be converted into `System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, object>>`.

Am I giving a wrong source type? or is this type IGouping type handled differently? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 Parallel.ForEach<IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, object>>, IEnumerable<object>>
                        (spotColletionByWeek,
                         () => new List<object>(),
                         (week, loop, summary) =>
                         {
                             summary.Add(new object()
                             {
                                            p1 = week.First().someprop,
                                            p2= week.key,
                                            .....
                           });
                             return new List<object>();
                         },
                         (finalResult) => pSummary.AddRange(finalResult)
                        );
```

Comment: Lists are not thread safe.  Use a [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameter `TSource` is the element type, not the collection type. And the second type parameter represents the local storage type, so it should be `List<T>`, if you want to `Add()` to it. This should work:

```
Parallel.ForEach<IGrouping<DateTime, object>, List<object>>
```

That's assuming you don't actually have `object`s there, but some specific type.

Although explicit type parameters are not even necessary here. The compiler should be able to infer them.

But there are other problems in the code:

- you shouldn't return new `List` from the main delegate, but `summary`
- the delegate that processes `finalResult` might be executed concurrently on multiple threads, so you should use locks or a concurrent collection there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to skip the 'Are you sure you even need to optimize this' stage, and assume you have a performance issue which you hope to solve by parallelizing.

First of all, you're not doing yourself any favors trying to use `Parallel.Foreach<>` for this task. I'm pretty sure you will get a readable and more optimal result using PLINQ:

```
var random = new Random();
var weeks = new List<Week>();
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    weeks.Add(
      new Week {
          WeekStartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(7 * random.Next(0, 100))
      });
}

var parallelCollectionByWeek =
    (from item in weeks.AsParallel()
     group item by item.WeekStartDate into weekGroups
     select new
     {
       p1 = weekGroups.First().WeekStartDate,
       p2 = weekGroups.Key,
     }).ToList();
```

It's worth noting that there is some overhead associated with parallelizing the `GroupBy` operator, so the benefit will be marginal at best. (Some crude benchmarks hint at a 10-20% speed up)

Apart from that, the reason you're getting a compile error is because the first Type parameter is supposed to be an `IGrouping<DateTime, object>` and not an `IE<IG<..,..>>`.